# How can I pass thread counts and initial delay as variables in ultimate thread group?

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-4.0

I want to pass these thread counts, i.e 1,2,3 as variables with auto increment, and initial delay also as a variable:
[image: variables]

In ultimate thread group, I need to pass thread count and initial delay as variables. It should start a loop, which automatically starts the thread after given period of time. How can I achieve that?

I want something like this, which runs number of threads in loop:
[image: loop]

Comment: If you want to embed an image add it as `![](imageLink)`

Answer (score 0):

Below approach can work,
1) Use "once only controller"> Capture thread number and can be manipulated as per need in Java bean shell processor(if you want auto increment once for the user)> Add sleep time in this controller will delay thread execution

2) Out of "once only controller": Thread count is already captured you can auto increment in bean shell processor as per need.

I hope this will help you...